# How to find the maximum height of a launched projectile

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, projectile-motion

Given the probability density of launching a projectile at an angle $\theta$ directed above the horizontal such that $ f(\theta) = \begin{cases}
        K, & \text{$\frac{\pi}{6}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{3}$} \\
        0, & \text{otherwise} \\
        \end{cases} $. The maximum height reached by the projectile is $y=\frac{u^2}{2g}sin^2\theta$ where u is the initial speed and g is the magnitude of the gravitational acceleration.

I am first tasked to determine K and upon solving it, I found out that

$$K=\frac{6}{\pi}$$

For my second task I have to determine the probability density of the maximum height $h(y)$. I know that y is at maximum when $\theta$ is at maximum. So, it should be $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ so that $sin\theta=1$. I want to ask if it's correct to assume that
$$h(y) = \begin{cases}
        \frac{u^2}{2g}sin^2\theta, & \text{$0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$} \\
        0, & \text{otherwise} \\
        \end{cases} $$
If not, then do I have to relate the bounds to the constraint given on $f(\theta)$? If my understanding on how to find the probability density of $h(y)$ is wrong then can anyone guide me on how to attack this problem properly? Thank you for reading this post up until this point.

Comment: It should be obvious that you will have to take the bounds of the uniform distribution $f(\theta)$ into account; it is not possible to have $\theta > \frac\pi3$ or $\theta < \frac\pi6$, that is, two thirds of the interval from $0$ to $\frac\pi2$ is ruled out.

Comment: What is not obvious to me is what is meant by "the probability density of the maximum height $h(y)$." Does it mean that $h(y)$ is the probability density of $y$, which is the maximum height, or does it mean that the maximum height is $h(y)$ and that you are looking for the probability density of $h(y)$? The second interpretation doesn't make much sense, since you already used $y$ as the name of the maximum height in the equation $y=\frac{u^2}{2g}sin^2\theta.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value for $K$ is correct.

Hint:

We have $\theta\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(\pi/6,\pi/3)$ and $Y=c \sin^2\theta$ where $c>0$. Then $Y$ is a monotone transformation of $\theta$ and has probability density
$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{3}{\pi\sqrt{y(c-y)}},\quad y\in[c/4,3c/4].
$$
You're job is now to figure out why that's the solution. You may want to look up the change of variables formula for probability densities.